# jQuery: Scrolling effect for images (includes example)

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to imitate the scrolling effect seen on this page: http://www.google.de/nexus/5/

1. The are with the image and the text "Ihre Momente, wie Sie sie..." has an image but when the mouse scrolls, the image moves inside its container.
2. Further down is a mobile phone (unter the "Alles, was Sie brauchen um festzuhalten, was wirklich zählt" header). Its possible to use the scroll wheel to scroll images up and down inside the display of the mobile phone.

How could I implement something like that, I have no idea where to start. I can use jQuery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like jQuery's Parallax to me: http://stephband.info/jparallax/

Here's another implementation: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw this I dissected it with Firebug, it turns out it's really rather cleverly simple.

When your scroll reaches that point the elements containing a phone with a transparent center and the white background are "position: fixed" so that they scroll with you, as you scroll down the page it's simply passing in front of a bunch of image elements.

Though it may not be as quick and easy to implement like some plugins, it's all just a matter of detecting where you have scrolled to and adjusting some CSS properties.